# Visual Studio 2013 SPA Template Javascript documentation

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-spa

Does anyone know of any documentation or worked examples of building on the Visual Studio 2013 SPA template (as of Jan 2014)? I am particularly interested in the general architecture of the Javascript code, how this is structured the changes needed when adding new controllers and areas etc. I am relatively new to Javascript and JQuery but not software development in general.

When I search on-line for "ASP.NET SPA template" there are lots of hits for Hot Towel and other templates and the VS2012.2 SPA template which seems to be structured differently but I have found nothing related to building on the vanilla SPA template that comes out of the box with Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Answer (score 0):

Dissecting And Refactoring Visual Studio 2013 SPA Template: http://vs2013spatemplate.blogspot.de/